# Add List to Empty Data Frame in Pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

This is similar to this post "Appending to an empty data frame in Pandas?" but what I want is I have 2 lists

```
titles = ['Style','Occupancy','Ext_Wall_2','Roof_Cover','Int_Wall_2','Int_flr_2','Heat_Type','TTL_Bed','TTl_Half_Bath','TTL_Rooms','Kit_Style']

Bld_list = ['Colonial', '1', '\xa0', 'Asphalt', '\xa0', '\xa0','Forced Air-Duc',
 '4 Bedrooms', '2', '8',  'Average']
```

I want to create a dataframe that would have titles as column headers across and ten row 0 of the dataframe be the bld_list value so it would be 1 x 11 dataframe

I tried the follow from the post but it gave the following error >>> "unhashable type: 'list'".  I think the answer has to be very simple but I cant figure it out.  Let me know if you can help.  thank you

```
df6 = pd.DataFrame()
data = pd.DataFrame({columns:bld_list})
df6.append(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
In [88]: pd.DataFrame([Bld_list], columns=titles)
Out[88]:
      Style Occupancy Ext_Wall_2 Roof_Cover Int_Wall_2 Int_flr_2       Heat_Type     TTL_Bed TTl_Half_Bath TTL_Rooms Kit_Style
0  Colonial         1               Asphalt                       Forced Air-Duc  4 Bedrooms             2         8   Average
```

Answer (score 1):

You want do something as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

titles = ['Style','Occupancy','Ext_Wall_2','Roof_Cover','Int_Wall_2','Int_flr_2','Heat_Type','TTL_Bed','TTl_Half_Bath','TTL_Rooms','Kit_Style']

Bld_list = ['Colonial', '1', '\xa0', 'Asphalt', '\xa0', '\xa0', 'Forced Air-Duc', '4 Bedrooms', '2', '8',  'Average']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Title1':titles, 'Title2':Bld_list})
print(df)
```

Comment: That give the titles in DF as Title1 and Title2.  and it presents the data vertically in a 11x2 dataframe (2 columns 11 rows).  

I want the titles to be the titles in the names in the "titles" list and the 1st row (row 0) in the DF to be the info in the "bld_list" list.  So it will be 11 columns and 1 row

Comment: @JWestwood I misunderstood what you were asking. Please accept Max's answer as it is correct.

Comment: Max your suggestion worked. Thank you,   Parfait when I pass your comments I get the following  >>> If using all scalar values, you must pass an index.  Any idea how to edit >> trying to learn new code.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider a dictionary comprehension:

```
df <- pd.DataFrame({t:b for t,b in zip(titles, Bld_list)})
```